# max_allowed_packet set on server using WHM vps

Tags: mysql, vps, whm

I want to change max_allowed_packet on server using WHM vps.

but I am not getting at where it located, so please help me

I have tried

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet =1073741824;
```

but its not working its required super admin.

how to edit mysql.ini in WHM vps

same with httpd.conf, how to edit setting of apache in WHM ?

Answer (score 4):

Ahoy,

You can not edit the servers my.cnf file from inside WHM, you will need to edit this file using she ssh command line. To learn how to connect to your server using ssh please see:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ShellAccess

Once you are connected to your server with the root login using ssh, you will want to issue the following command to edit  my.cnf:

```
# nano -w /etc/my.cnf
```

In this file you will want to add a line under the [mysqld] section with the following contents:

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

You will now want to press *Ctrl + O* to save, and then *Ctrl + X* to exit.  You will now want to restart the MySQL server through WHM or on the command line with:

```
 # /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

This will update the max_allowed_packet for cPanel/WHM's mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Change in the `my.ini/my.cnf` file. Include the single line under `[mysqld]` in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

now restart the MySQL service once you are done. You can see it's current value in mysql like this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

You can read about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: but how to open this file in whm?